# Cannot findword in each line python

Tags: python

My text file is something like this.

```
RT @Vevo The @5SoS world is turned upside down in Want You Back the first release in 2 years by the Aussie poppunk band 
RT @Jeff__Benjamin Congratulations to @Stray_Kids for making their debut on @Billboard's Social 50 chart this week at No 45 Very promisi
RT @Vevo The @5SoS world is turned upside down in Want You Back the first release in 2 years by the Aussie poppunk band 
RT @thesheetztweetz Fun fact @relativityspace CEO Tim Ellis shared
The song is by @bassnectar and when he saw this video he told Relat
RT @Jeff__Benjamin Congratulations to @Stray_Kids for making their debut on @Billboard's Social 50 chart this week at No 45 Very promisi
RT @fringeflowers What a Beautiful Way to Express Your Spirituality with this #SterlingSilver Fancy Vented Band with #Sanskrit The Langua
```

My code file is like below.

```
import re

wordlist = ["soundigest","vile","paris" ,"carlyaquilino","chrispolanco13","bimbo's","mcr","jack","lauren_hoggs","siriusxm","force","7th","muz4now","christ","orchestra","100","rampb","gla"]

data = ""
counter=0
with open("musicData.txt","w") as fout:
    print "hi"
    with open("temp.txt") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            for term in line.split():
                term = term.lower()
                term= re.sub('[\n]+', ' ', term)
                # Remove not alphanumeric symbols white spaces
                term = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', term)
                # Replace #word with word
                term = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', term)
                # Remove :( or :)
                term = term.replace(':)', '')
                term = term.replace(':(', '')
                # trim
                term = term.strip('\'"')
                if term in wordlist:
                    data = data + term + ","
                    print data
            if data !="":
                fout.write(data)
                #print "data to write :", data
                fout.write("\n") 
            data =""
```

My goal is, I want to find each line array which has the word from the wordlist. so suppose for first line it will have two words from wordlist then it will print the array in new file like [vile, paris]. I'm not able to do with the current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you making it more complicated than it should be

What if you do like this ?

```
with open("temp.txt") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            for word in wordlist:
                if word in line:
                    # or data = data + line + "," - depends what you want to get
                    data = data + word + ","
                    print data
```

Comment: That will match 'christoph' with 'christ'. But one could compile the word list into a regexp of kind `r"\b(escaped1|escaped2)\b"` and match with the regexp on word boundaries only.